# `command not found` when trying to stop MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb-10.3

On OS X I need to reset the password of MySQL. It was installed with Homebrew.

I found this article which explains how reset my password: https://dev.to/oneearedmusic/access-denied-reset-mysql-root-user-password-2hk4

However, step 1 gives me issues. It says:

> Shut down Mysql. Try
>
> sudo service mysql stop
>
> or
>
> sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
>
> or looking up the PID and killing it.

The first two options give me:

> `command not found`

I'm searching for how to 'look up' the PID, what it is, and how to use it, but I'm getting a lot of noise so far in my search results...

Why am I getting `command not found`. How can I stop my server?

I'm using version 15.1 Distrib 10.3.13-MariaDB, for osx10.14 (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Answer (score 1):

This might work on all OSs:

```
mysqladmin shutdown
```

Answer (score 0):

There are variety of ways to restart MySQL in MacOS (before MySQL 5.7)

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

or for MySQL 5.7 up

```
sudo launchctl unload -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
sudo launchctl unload -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

Comment: The first stop gives me `command not found`. The second gives me `No such file or directory`.

Comment: @user187302 - Different OSs put the files in different places.  _You_ must locate it.  Be aware that the name could be quite different.  `mysql` is a client tool, so that name is wrong.  The daemon is called `mysqld`, but it might go by `mysql.server`.  Etc, etc.